True or false: "The real line $\mathbb{R}$ is a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$."?
In the section on topology of his Advanced Calculus of Several Variables C. H. Edwards writes:

The real line $\mathbb{R}$ is a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Is this correct?
One argument, which I have been assured is irrefutable, is that $\mathbb{R}$ is not a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ since $\mathbb{R}^2$ is a set of ordered pairs, whereas $\mathbb{R}$ is a set of numbers.  Given other statements in his book, Edwards seems to hold a different view which would support the above quoted assertion.

Pretty sure he means that if you identify $\mathbb{R}$ with the subset ${(x,0): x\in\mathbb{R}}$ of $\mathbb{R^2}$. This is exactly how we always identify $\mathbb{R}$ as a subset of $\mathbb{C}$.

Then $R^{n}$ is a subset of $R^{n+1}$?  What you are referring to is similar to identifying the natural numbers with the corresponding rational numbers, and rational numbers with the corresponding real numbers, etc.  The set ${(\mathfrak{x},0): \mathfrak{x}\in\mathbb{R}^n}$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$.  When I have suggested that under certain definitions $R^{n}$ is a subspace of $R^{n+1}$ my questions have been down-voted and removed.

The set $\mathbb{R}$ is definitely not a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$. Whenever someone says that it is the case, they are using a very common abuse of notation, which is to say that by $x$, they mean $(x,0)$ (more precisely, we can "identify" some objet to some other object via a bijective map). As long as you are aware of it, it is fine. But it is definitely wrong to insist that $\mathbb{R} \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ holds literally.

You are correct but, unfortunately, this is done a lot in mathematics. My least favorite is $\sqrt{-1}$ but calling an equation like $x^2+y^2=1$ a circle is almost as bad.

@JohnDouma What's the problem with calling this equation a circle?

@Mark A circle is the set of solutions to that equation. The equation is itself is just a formula with two free variables. The unit circle $S^1={(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2: x^2+y^2=1}$.

@JohnDouma I don't know, in algebraic geometry it sometimes makes sense to identify polynomials with their zeros. I agree that identifications are sometimes taken way too far (and in some cases it causes problems), but in some cases they also help. For example, we do want to think of $\mathbb{N}\subseteq\mathbb{Z}\subseteq\mathbb{Q}\subseteq\mathbb{R}\subseteq\mathbb{C}$ as actual inclusions, though by pure definitions, none of them are.

@Mark There are several possible ways to define the sets $\Bbb N, \Bbb Z, \ldots$ and in some of them, those are actually inclusions.

@Mark Yes, that's the point. We do it everywhere. Otherwise, every statement we make would be too verbose. I don't think any of our topology instructors would be happy if we said $\mathbb Q$ is not dense in $\mathbb R$ because it is not contained in $\mathbb R$.

@JohnDouma $i=\sqrt{-1}$ such that $i^2=-1$ is not a result.  It is a definition.  As long as it does not contradict other definitions and results, or any such contradictions are acknowledged and addressed, it is perfectly legal mathematics.

@StevenThomasHatton $i$ is the square root of $(-1,0)$ in the complex plane. It is no different than your issue about $\mathbb R\subset\mathbb R^2$. The real numbers are isomorphic to the set of $r+0i$ in $\mathbb C$.

When discussing the inclusion $\mathbb{R}\subseteq\mathbb{R}^2$ one must define the appropriate embedding i.e $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^2$ defined by $f(x)=(x,0)$, otherwise, that statement is meaningless.
After finding the appropriate embedding, you can ask whether it is an open/closed subset. In this case, it is easy to show that $\mathbb{R}$ is closed as every point in $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\mathbb{R}$ has an open neighborhood.

The subset $\mathbb{R}$ is often supposed to be embedded in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ (think about it geometrically as a line in a plane). There are of course different methods of embedding (any set $\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^{2}\mid ay + bx = c \text{ for } a,b,c\in\mathbb{R} \text{ and $a$, $b$, $c$ not simultaneously $0$} \}$ will do), but the most straightforward, as mentioned in comments  is by identifying $\mathbb{R}$ with points $(x,0)\in\mathbb{R}^{2}$.
Why is it closed? Well, there are different ways to see it.
For example, if you think about a closed set $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}^{2}$ as such that $\mathbb{R}^{2}\setminus A$ is open, then note, that any point in $\mathbb{R}^{2}\setminus \mathbb{R}$ admits a neighborhood which lies in $\mathbb{R}^{2}\setminus \mathbb{R}$, thus $\mathbb{R}^{2}\setminus \mathbb{R}$ is open and therefore $\mathbb{R}$ is closed.
Equivalently a closed set is a set containing all its limit points. Obviously $\mathbb{R}$ contains all its limit points by definition of real numbers.

I don't believe this is simply an abuse of notion on Edwards's part.  I believe it was a willful act of defiance.

Yes, seems weird!

Which page is this?

Page 50, Example (d) immediately preceding Proposition 8.1

Actually I don't see where this interferes with the answer I gave or with other answers and comments. The idea of $\mathbb{R}$ is embedded into $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ is definitely what is meant there. I think that if you're doing something except very specific cases of algebra or set-theory, this is even not considered as an abuse of notation, this is just the notation for $(\mathbb{R},0)\subset\mathbb{R}^{2}$.

I'm not disagreeing with you.  But $\mathbb R=\left(\mathbb{R},0\right)$ means $\mathbb{R}$ is a vector subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$ which is simply not done in "polite" company.
